# What is the bitcoind command to see how much btc a specific address has?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind

I was wondering if I can make a query via the console on how much btc a specific address has without having to go into blockchain.info. What is this command?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such command. Addresses are like a superstructure over a bitcoin transaction processing. Client does not maintain index with addresses and balances on them.

Comment: so how would one find out how much btc a specific address has if all you had was access to the entire downloaded blockchain?

Comment: You must scan entire blockchain, to find out in which transactions this address participates.

Comment: is there an offline application that can scan the blockchain to do this kind of functionality?

Comment: I don't know. Why you cannot use blockchain.info? They have an API for such queries.

Comment: i just want to know how i would do it if i do not have internet access to blockchain.info

Answer (score -1):

There is no command in bitcoind to view the balance of a single wallet. Your best luck is setting up a script with cURL that gets the data from api.

Comment: @NateEldredge I see, Well the best option in linux is to do cURL from api as there is no command. I edited my post also.

Comment: @duckx Is it that you dont have internet access or is it that your doing this from SSH or Command?